# So - Multi Draw Indirect, or batching?

Tags: opengl

I am not sure which one is better. Is Multi Draw Indirect just an easier, better, way than batching everything into one regular draw call, if you're using 4.3+? You can use VertexAttribDivisor with this, for example...

And you also don't have to setup a batching system yourself (it would require some work to get multi draw indirect to work, but it has some advantages which makes it seem easier to implement, and may be faster than a home-made batching system).

What are people's thoughts on this?

Comment: isn't multidrawindirect *even better* "batching"? You could multi-draw-indirect just one batch, or lots of batches at once